# How do I specify a return type based on callback's return type?

Tags: typescript, promise

The following interface defines a function that takes a callback function and returns the value returned by the callback.

```js
export interface MonitoredOperation {
    <T = any>(operationName: string, operation: () => T | Promise<T>): T | Promise<T>;
}
```

The problem is that if I use this function in a context where the callback will always return one of the types, TypeScript still thinks the outer function can return either type.

For example, if I write the following code,

```js
public addNumbersAsync(n1: number, n2: number, n3: number, n4: number): Promise<number> {
    return this.monitoredOperation("addNumbers", () => Promise.resolve(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4));
}
```

TypeScript complains that it can't assign `number | Promise<number>` to `Promise<number>`.

I've seen some examples where `infer` is used to capture the return value of a function, but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

How can I tell TypeScript both the information I have here and that the return types must match?

EDIT:

I need both possible types because my implementation of this interface needs to distinguish between them. If my interface only uses `T`, I get an error of `Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'T'`. Here is a simplified version:

```js
function monitoredOperation<T>(operationName: string, operation: () => T | Promise<T>): T | Promise<T> {
    let onSuccess = (value: T): T => {
        broadcast("finished");
        return value;
    }
    let onFailure = (error: any): never => {
        broadcast("failed");
        throw error;
    }

    try {
        let result = operation();

        if (isPromise(result)) {
            return result.then(onSuccess, onFailure);
        } else {
            return onSuccess(result);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        onFailure(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What value (ie type safety) is added `| Promise<T>`. This would work just as well: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQiQRmmABMB5MNTGBIuAbwCg44AeAFTgF45MSAJ4A+ABQQaUOgyQA5TAFtgALjgBnGFGQBzADRxJtekTViAlHxFwu5tVwDcLAL4sW2ADaZ16uAA1mNjgwbQA3OjxFIhIyKikZIgBCNUJiUigKamNZILAAVwAjDwRsAXJyOTzFArR1AEF1ISRsMSQARjUkKpqoAyQAJk7utD6AZiHqkbgkABYJnrs4AAUoCEUEdWAOLsmoa1Z2dgyYPKgkOBgACw2AOii02KzpEyQxACJMcsrd9TeDCysy1W602Nwy6ggHlCwFabTgAGppv0EdNRijZuZzE52K5XG58SwgA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is gained by the `| Promise<T>`. The behavior of the function from a type perspective is actually correct without it. `monitoredOperation` returns what the callback returns, whatever that is, `Promise` or otherwise:

```
interface MonitoredOperation {
  <T = any>(operationName: string, operation: () => T): T;
}

class X {
  private monitoredOperation!: MonitoredOperation
  public addNumbersAsync(n1: number, n2: number, n3: number, n4: number): Promise<number> {
    return this.monitoredOperation("addNumbers", () => Promise.resolve(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4));
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsTDOqEAmA8gA7RxjCbIDeAUMsgDwAqyAvMnCAJ4B8AFOlJRylEADk4AWwgAuZAGcwUUAHMANMiFkKmefwCU7XsmYH5zANy0AvrVoIANnAULkADRr1kxFQDdyFClMbFwCEh0xAEJ5DCwcPCJhUUxvYgBXACNHYAROfHxxdKlM6AUAQQVuEAR+EABGeRBi0qhNEAAmJpbodoBmbpLe5BAAFkHW82QABSh0KWAFCEZmoagTOgYGPDB0qBBkMAALRYA6YPiwpMjMfgAiOAKitYU7zUNjGbmFpdO8BXQjj8EDq9WQAGoRh0ISM+jCxgYDNYGHYbEA)

If you want to keep the `Promise` in the signature (perhaps for documentation, hinting at special `Promise` behavior) overloads will work better:

```
interface MonitoredOperation {
  <T = any>(operationName: string, operation: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
  <T = any>(operationName: string, operation: () => T): T;
}

class X {
  private monitoredOperation!: MonitoredOperation
  public addNumbersAsync(n1: number, n2: number, n3: number, n4: number): Promise<number> {
    return this.monitoredOperation("addNumbers", () => Promise.resolve(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4));
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsTDOqEAmA8gA7RxjCbIDeAUMsgDwAqyAvMnCAJ4B8AFOlJRylEADk4AWwgAuZAGcwUUAHMANMiFkKmefwCU7XsgAKUdFOAKILXgfnnL12814Buek1YcufQcKimJIy8koqIBpagbog+kZsJswOyMyeAL60tAgANnAKCsgAGjRexCoAbuQoUpjYuAQkOmIAhPIYWDh4RDFiZQCuAEY5wAic+Pji-VKD0AoAggrcIAj8IACM8iDTs1CaIABMWzvQ+wDMxzOnyCAALJe7KU5WNozbV1AmdAwMeGD9UBAyDAAAtrAA6WqdBo9ZqYfgAIjgEymHwUCM0hmMZgsLwg4LwCnQOQqEDW62QAGobgcqTcznS7gYDJ4GJl0kA)

Comment: I need both possible types because my implementation of this interface needs to distinguish between them. Your second solution therefore works well. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBest if it's just an implementation detail why not just use a separate implementation signature:https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsTDOqEAmA8gA7RxjCbIDeAUMsgDwAqyAvMnCAJ4B8AFOlJRylEADk4AWwgAuZAGcwUUAHMANMiFkKmefwCU7XsmYH5zANy0AvrRgBXEAl0hkUzNlwESOsS3ZOHgFtEVdJGXklFRANLWFRPWRDY1NzU2tHZ1d3Txw8IgTXFhCisQi5RWU1TVDEkH0jNhMABSh0KWAFCBLkAB80+TaOrp7mEwHWOgY8MAcoNzrXQ2s7WgAbCDB3eQwsfJ8yqg4Pfe9Cv0xLZAB6G-QAayA